# Vaadin 7 : RPC call from Server to Client

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to create custom image component .So I followed step by step from [Integrating with Server-side](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.html). For basic or first-step , I created for the test ***[Server to Client RPC call](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+RPC+to+send+events+to+the+client)*** as following steps.

**MyComponentWidget.java**

```
public class MyComponentWidget extends HTML {

public MyComponentWidget() {
    getElement().setAttribute("class", "thumbnail");
}

public final void createCustomImage(final String url) {
 getElement().setInnerHTML("<div class='delete-block'></div><img src=" + url + " />");
}
}
```

**MyComponentState.java**

```
public class MyComponentState extends AbstractComponentState {
private String url;
private String html;

public final String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public final void setUrl(final String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public final String getHtml() {
    return html;
}

public final void setHtml(final String html) {
    this.html = html;
}
}
```

**MyComponentConnector.java**

```
public class MyComponentConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {

public MyComponentConnector() {
    registerRpc(MyComponentClientRpc.class, new MyComponentClientRpc() {

        @Override
        public void getMessage() {
            // never reach to this place
            System.err.println("Reach Here !");
            getState().setHtml(getWidget().getHTML());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public final MyComponentWidget getWidget() {
    return (MyComponentWidget) super.getWidget();
}

@Override
public final MyComponentState getState() {
    return (MyComponentState) super.getState();
}

@OnStateChange("url")
final void updateText() {
    getWidget().createCustomImage(getState().getUrl());
}
}
```

**MyComponentClientRpc.java**

```
import com.vaadin.shared.communication.ClientRpc;
public interface MyComponentClientRpc extends ClientRpc {
void getMessage();
}
```

**MyComponent.java**

```
public class MyComponent extends AbstractComponent {

public MyComponent(final String url) {
    getState().setUrl(url);
}

public final MyComponentState getState() {
    return (MyComponentState) super.getState();
}

public final String getHTML() {
    getRpcProxy(MyComponentClientRpc.class).getMessage();
    return getState().getHtml();
}
}
```

and call as

```
MyComponent image = new MyComponent("myImageUrl");
System.out.println(image.getHTML());
```

My problem is why I always get *null* value at my console ? I can see the image at browser but ***System.out.println(image.getHTML());*** produces *null*. What am I missing ?

Comment: for 2) the superdevmode supposedly takes 10s to rebuild https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-and-superdevmode

Comment: @cfrick now I am prepare new question for 2 . Thanks.

Comment: @Cataclysm What are you trying to do exactly. Send a RPC message from server to browser?

Comment: @HenriKerola No sir, I am trying to get HTML representation of widget from server. So I call `image.getHTML()` and set **html** value of componentstate from client rpc method as `getState().setHtml(getWidget().getHTML());`. I debugged but I never invoke to clientrpc method. What am I wrong sir ?

Answer (score -1):

To make a rpc call from client to server, you must extend the `ServerRpc` interface, for example:

```
package com.example.client.MyServerRpc

public interface MyServerRpc extends com.vaadin.shared.communication.ServerRpc {
    void sendHTML(String html);
}
```

In your connector your register the rpc:

```
private MyServerRpc rpc = RpcProxy.create(MyServerRpc.class, this);
```

And then you can send a value by using the registered rpc in your connector:

```
 rpc.sendHTML(html);
```

To receive the value on your component's or extension's server-side class, you must create an instance of the rpc interface:

```
private MyServerRpc rpc = new MyServerRpc() {
    @Override
    public void sendHTML(String html) {
        // this method will be called!
    }

};
```

and register that in the constructor:

```
registerRpc(rpc);
```

After these steps RPC from client to server should work.

Comment: Sir ! Thanks for your answer , but my question title is `Vaadin 7 : RPC call from Server to Client`.

Comment: **Server to Client** so , I used *ClientRpc* not **Client to Server**.

Comment: In the question's comment you say, you want to transfer a value to server.

Comment: Yes sir ! I would like to transfer HTML representation of widget from client side to server but if I want to transfer anythings from client to server , I need some events. So I call from server component without any events of client. So I used clientrpc to call rpc from server to client. If I am wrong , pls correct me sir. Thanks , I really appreciate any of your suggestions.